# Error while loading Draco-compressed mesh (glTF-Transform) in BabylonJS

Tags: compression, mesh, gltf, babylonjs

I am trying to load Draco-compressed meshes, processed server-side with [glTF-Transform](https://gltf-transform.dev/), in BabylonJS retrieving them on the fly via REST calls. Due to this, the mesh to load doesn’t have an extension, because it is a blob in memory and the method `URL.createObjectURL()` (which is being used to have a URL for such blob) doesn’t allow to specify an extension or a custom URL. If one tries to import the blob as it is, `SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync()` seems to not know how to load it and gives

```
createModelRenderable.ts:520 Error during loading meshes, try again RuntimeError: Unable to load from blob:http://127.0.0.1:5173/b3b55baa-4ede-41fd-a66e-304460969a7f: importMesh of undefined from undefined version: undefined, exporter version: undefinedimportMesh has failed JSON parse
    at A (sceneLoader.js:343:46)
    at Object.importMesh (babylonFileLoader.js:797:17)
    at sceneLoader.js:382:35
    at A (sceneLoader.js:182:13)
    at fileTools.js:375:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.A (fileTools.js:489:33)
```

without being even able to load a classic .glb. That’s why you have to specify “.glb” as the `pluginExtension` parameter of `ImportMeshAsync` to make it work. By doing so, the classic `glb` will load, but the draco-compressed one won't because (maybe? I suppose) its schema definition doesn't specify any extension
[mesh.primitive.KHR_draco_mesh_compression.schema.json](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_draco_me%5B%E2%80%A6%5Don/schema/mesh.primitive.KHR_draco_mesh_compression.schema.json)

```
createModelRenderable.ts:519 Error during loading meshes, try again RuntimeError: Unable to load from blob:http://127.0.0.1:5173/07f9e64c-2c58-4c64-81c0-54f7d3bbb586: (this.dracoCompression || E8.Default)._decodeMeshToGeometryForGltfAsync is not a function
    at A (sceneLoader.js:343:46)
    at sceneLoader.js:397:21
```

By the way, the `KHR_draco_mesh_compression` is loaded because trying to add it again will raise a warning saying that *“there’s no need to add the KHR_draco_mesh_compression extension because it’s already present”*.
I have already checked that draco’s configuration was ok, and the default one points to a valid CDN

```
wasmUrl: “https://preview.babylonjs.com/draco_wasm_wrapper_gltf.js”
wasmBinaryUrl: “https://preview.babylonjs.com/draco_decoder_gltf.wasm”
fallbackUrl: “https://preview.babylonjs.com/draco_decoder_gltf.js”
```

the decoder wasm is downloaded correctly. I have anyway tried to use local files, but the result was the same.

I'm also sure that the mesh is a valid Draco compressed GLB file, because it loads correctly on https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/

I also tried loading the mesh as a file with something classic like

```
const loadFileAsync = function (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    LoadFile(
      url,
      function (data) {
        resolve(data);
      },
      undefined,
      undefined,
      true,
      function (_request, exception) {
        reject(exception);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

and then decode its Draco-compressed part with `new DracoCompression().decodeMeshAsync()` to mix it then with texture and the rest but no luck again getting *"Not a Draco file."* in response.

Seems the same issue is faced [in this post on BabylonJS forum](https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/errors-when-trying-to-load-draco-compressed-mesh/46665/5), still without any working solution.

Comment: Your error message `undefinedimportMesh has failed JSON parse` seems to suggest that it's a browser issue reading from a BLOB or something, not related to the glTF itself.   Can you investigate DevTools network panel and see if you're getting a 403 or some other error?

Comment: Just checked, I get a 200 OK in response

Comment: In that case I think you have to trap the text being fed into `JSON.parse` that's giving you the parse failure.  Is it trying to parse the binary contents of the GLB?  Or is it trying to parse some non-JSON error message?  Clearly it's not parsing the JSON payload from the glTF file, given the glTF file works fine in other viewers.

Comment: good catch, effectively not specifying the plugin extension, Babylon was using a loader with extension .babylon which was trying to parse the whole file as a json, instead of extracting the json header and then load the binary data. By specifying .glb instead, the loader being used is correct, but it seems to not have the draco plugin. even though adding it manually says it's already loaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging BabylonJS' core I discovered that using “.glb” was right and it was using the correct loader (*glTFLoader*), but there was a version mismatch in babylon’s imports causing a function not to be found, namely, `_decodeMeshToGeometryForGltfAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PG example with Draco mesh loading from blob - https://playground.babylonjs.com/#FIWM5X#45

Comment: Even though it works in there, with the same exact lines it doesn't in my project. I'm starting to wonder if it might be caused by any incompatibility with other libraries I have. I double-checked BabylonJS version and is 6.18, so it should work.